# Closing an Activity in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver to check the internet connectivity, in which i have validated if no internet connection I am displaying an error screen through intent. Now i need to close the error screen when the network is reconnected and display the previous screen from which the network was gone.

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        isConnected = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectionDetector.CONNECTED_KEY, false);
        if(isConnected){
            System.out.println("A1");
            finish();
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(CONNECTION_BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
            System.out.println("A2");
            No_Network.this.finish();
        }
    }
};
```

This is my code inside the error screen activity. How to close the activity here? finish() is not working.

Comment: You should use `context.finish();` which will be cast to your activity.

Comment: context.finish() shows error cannot resolve finish()

Comment: You should cast your activity. Does the BR is in your activity or is it a outer custom class??

Comment: This BroadcastReceiver BR is in my Activity & ConnectionDetector BR is outer class

Comment: Then simply call **(YourActivityName)context.finish();**

Answer (score 0):

> How to close the activity here? finish() is not working

It is "not working" because you are not using it correctly. The correct approach is to notify the activity and tell it to `finish()` itself. You can do that by sending intent with "magic" code of yours directly to your activity (if it is in `singleTop` launch mode then `startActivity()` + `onNewIntent()` would suffice). Alternatively use event bus for communication.

Comment: Sorry can you please brief more? I couldn't understand